# How to call "Controller".listJson() from dojo.xhrGet

Tags: spring-roo

I am very new working with spring roo, ajax and json, and I have a question. Roo create two method in controllers class for list all element of a entity if you use some roo shell commands , one for ajax/json and one without json.

ajax/json method annotation are

```
@RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/json")
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<String> "Controller".listJson()
```

and the other method is:

```
 @RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
     public String "Controller".list
```

both method have this path @RequestMapping("/admtpcomunidads")

when I try to call ajax/json method from javascript with dojo, I use:

```
dojo.xhrGet({url: "admtpcomunidads",
              handleAs: 'json',
```

but the call links to "Controller.list" method and no to "Controller.listJson" method. What url do I need to use in the dojo.xhrGet call to link with listJson Method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Dojo but from jquery I did such:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"/[projectName]/[EntityName]s",    
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj)
        {
          xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
        },

    }).done(function(data ) {             
           $.each(data, function(index) {
           alert(data[index].field)                
            });

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {       
            alert( "error: " +jqXHR.responseText +"-status: "+textStatus + "status:" +jqXHR.status);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, but the problem is that spring roo create two method that in my opinion, can be matched with the same url, in this case if I use the url "projectName/EntitiName"  the method matched is : @RequestMapping(produces = "text/html")
     public String "Controller".list
however   I want to match this method:           @RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/json")
 @ResponseBody
 public ResponseEntity<String>Controller".listJson() Maybe I need to put some data in the header request to match the listJson method but I don't know how.

Comment: I think you can:  headers:{
                          "Content-Type": "application/json"
                         , "Accept": "application/json"
                    }, handleAs: "json",

Comment: Thanks Ali, I have tested headers:{ "Content-Type": "application/json" , "Accept": "application/json" }, handleAs: "json" but I get a "NetworkError: 406 No Aceptable error in firebug console.